# How can we access message from iMessage ?

Tags: ios, imessage

Is it possible to access iMessages ? How to send iMessages programmatically ?
Apple iOS provide any public API to access or delete Messages ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to send messages ([Sending an iMessage as simple as possible iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10850122/)) but it isn't possible to read and delete messages.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides this in their SDK through MessageUI, check the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161

You could look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10850188.

Answer (score 0):

They just announced some stuff yesterday that might be of some use for you - it's the new `Messages` framework. You've got some handy classes there like `MSMessage` and `MSConversation`, but just explore and read more below:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/messages

Comment: So, Is it possible to read messages?